# Normalize Function in Python

Tags: python, pygame, ellipse, normalize

I'm currently working on a paint program using python 2.7.5 and pygame.  I came across an error with the ellipse tool and asked a classmate for some help and he said I was missing a .normalize().  I added it in and my tool was fixed.  I'm currently just wondering what that function does.  Here's the code it is used in:

```
        if mb[0] == 1 and canvas.collidepoint(mx,my):
        screen.set_clip(canvas)
        if tool == "ellipse":
            screen.blit(copy,(0,0))
            radius = Rect(startx,starty,mx-startx,my-starty)    #Area Ellipse is being drawn
            radius.normalize()
        if radius.height<sz2*2 or radius.width<sz2*2:
            draw.ellipse(screen,(c),(radius))
        else:
            draw.ellipse(screen,(c),(radius), sz2)
        screen.set_clip(None)
```

Comment: Read the docs: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.normalize

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just asking for the documentation for a function, and any reasonable answer will just be [this link](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.normalize).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First result googling "PyGame Rect Normalize":

[PyGame Rect Docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.normalize)

```
normalize()
correct negative sizes
normalize() -> None
```

> This will flip the width or height of a rectangle if it has a negative size. The rectangle will remain in the same place, with only the sides swapped.

So in essence it ensures the width and height are positive, not negative.

Comment: Thank you!  I obviously wasn't googling the right things.